# Git submodule for Linux and Windows

Tags: git, git-submodules

When using `git submodule` on Linux I might have a `.gitmodules` with one or more subsystems checked out from e.g. `/mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git` (central file based access).

```
[submodule "subsystem1"]
  path = subsystem11
  url = /mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
```

I would like to support also a Windows user who can access the same module repo from `H:/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/`.

It is e.g. a Samba share from Linux of `/mnt/gitrepos/` as the share `gitrepos`.

Is there a way where Git can handle the URL line depending on the OS?
For Windows the `.gitmodules` would be

```
[submodule "subsystem1"]
  path = subsystem11
  url = H:/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
```

Thus I would like "something like" this generic code for `.gitmodules` (speculative syntax):

```
[submodule "subsystem1"]
  path = subsystem11
  if Linux 
    url = /mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
  else
    url = H:/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Submodules are generally designed for one repository URL that works everywhere, usually network-based (e.g. `git://host/path`). There is no mechanism for providing multiple different URLs for one repository.

That said, Git does allow you to customize a submodule's URL. When submodules are initialized (`git submodule init`), the URL from `.gitmodules` is copied to your `.git/config` file. You can now edit the URLs there before running `git submodule update`.

Comment: Which is why there is two stage initialisation for submodules - allowing the url to be changed in the local repository before actually cloning the submodule.

Comment: Nice! Very good explanation. I can add a converter script between "git submodule init" and "git submodule update --recursive"

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I've considered (but not tried) is to initialize the submodule codebase ("subsystem1.git" in your example) as an independent, local repository. Add a "remote" in the submodule which points to the independent, local version of the repository. Also add a "remote" in the non-submodule (indepent, local) version of your subsystem repository which points to the submodule version. You should then be able to use Samba / Windows / Linux to update the independent (non-submodule) version of subsystem1.git, and then "git fetch independent" from within the submodule to copy the code from the non-submodule repository to the submodule repository.

At the end, your directory structure should look something like:

```
/mnt/gitrepos/
/mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
/mnt/subsystem1.git/
```

The remotes in each of these repositories would look like the following:

```
/mnt/gitrepos/.git/config would have one remote block:
    [remote "origin"]   (points to your main, non-local repository)
/mnt/subsystem1.git/.git/config would have two remote blocks:
    [remote "origin"]   (points to your main, non-local repository)
    [remote "local_origin"]   (points to /mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git)
/mnt/gitrepos/.git/modules/subsystem1.git/config would also have two remote blocks:
    [remote "origin"]   (points to your main, non-local repository)
    [remote "independent"]   (points to /mnt/subsystem1.git)
```

Synchronizing your submodule's code with what's on the remote server then becomes a multi-step process, since you have to use the "independent" repository as an intermediate repository / staging area.

Your Mileage May Vary... This is just a thing that seems like it should work, not something I've tried.